# Debugging LINQ queries using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am looking for a reliable and an easy way to debug LINQ queries. I understand I can do the following:

1. LinqPad (Needs license)
2. Using the technique described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/11/07/debugging-linq-queries.aspx) (Need to update linq queries with `select`s)
3. [Extended Immediate window](http://extendedimmediatewin.codeplex.com/) (Not updated for VS 2010 environment)

Has anyone come across anything that can be integrated with VS 2010?

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Can you tell how can I use my licensed LinqPad to do this? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: My understanding is that you can setup LinqPad to point to your entities and copy paste linq query to test Linq to entities

Comment: AfAIK, LinqPad doesn't need a license if you are willing to forgoe their version of Intellisense and some other premium features.  I use it all the time and I've never paid for a license.  Also, I've attached LinqPad to my compiled DataContexts and have been able to use very successfully to test the results of my Linq queries.

Comment: Ok, I thought there was something more elaborate. If that's all you need, the free version works fine.

Comment: I am not necessarily looking for debugging linq queries for linq to entities. I am looking for a universal solution that can be integrated with VS 2010 for debugging any linq query.